# I need help regarding Ionic Hybrid App

Tags: ionic-framework

**Network is enabled but even App can't get Twitter feeds**, on localhost twitter apis are working, I have also install network plugin, need solution immediately please

**screen shots :** https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1f05ppa659v2ngc/AADnn2UifITTTYmyyndGwDaHa?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the whitelist plugin?

http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the problem on Android or iPhone?

If it Android, do you add permission in manifest?

Comment: working now thanks its for android i have add permission in manifest